# Numpy slicing leads to changed value

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working with some python code and one piece of code keeps ruining my day:

```py
print(img.shape) # prints (4, 64, 64, 3)
scaled = np.array(img, copy=True)                                                           
test = np.array(img, copy=True) / 255                                                                                                                                                                   
scaled[:, :, :, :3] = scaled[:, :, :, :3] / 255.0                                                                                                          
print(np.all(scaled == test)) # prints false
```

My problem here is that the slice operation seems to change the value of the operation. As far as I understand it, `scaled` and `test` should be the same. Am I just missing something or where exactly lies my error?

Comment: It's not a subset.  [...:3] gets all of the elements.

Comment: the shape of the img is (4, 64, 64, 3), so it shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` is stricter about data types than Python.  `img` is an integer datatype, so `scaled` is also an integer data type.  `test` is created as a float data type.  When you do the in-place division, it does a floating divide, then casts the result back to integer to store it in the array.

If you had printed out the two arrays, this would have been obvious.

Comment: thank you very much, this was my exact problem

Comment: Nice explanation (+1), maybe provide a quick fix? (Changing type to float)

Comment: `scaled = np.array(img, copy=True).astype(np.float64)` worked for me

Comment: Well, the fix depends on whether you wanted the results in float or integer.  With image data, either one is possible.  As a side note, if you're converting the datatype, you don't need `copy=True`.  It will clearly have to make a new copy with the new datatype.